# PHP send mail mixing up form labels or not showing at all

Tags: php, forms, sendmail

I'm trying to make this sendmail form but it will either not show any input, or put the input in a different field although a couple of them seem to work for some reason. I have the form at http://nomaddad.net/market/apply.html

The PHP i'm using for it is:

```
    <?php
/*
This first bit sets the email address that you want the form to be submitted to.
You will need to change this value to a valid email address that you can access.
*/
$webmaster_email = "admin@centennialmarket.ca";

/*
This bit sets the URLs of the supporting pages.
If you change the names of any of the pages, you will need to change the values here.
*/
$feedback_page = "../contact.html";
$error_page = "error_message.html";
$thankyou_page = "../thankyou.html";

/*
This next bit loads the form field data into variables.
If you add a form field, you will need to add it here.
*/
$busname = $_REQUEST['busname'] ;
$Applicant = $_REQUEST['Applicant'] ;
$street = $_REQUEST['street'] ;
$apartment = $_REQUEST['apartment'] ;
$city = $_REQUEST['city'] ;
$province = $_REQUEST['province'] ;
$postal = $_REQUEST['postal'] ;
$mainphone = $_REQUEST['mainphone'] ;
$cellphone = $_REQUEST['cellphone'] ;
$email_address = $_REQUEST['email_address'] ;
$website = $_REQUEST['website'] ;
$category = $_REQUEST['category'] ;
$directorder = $_REQUEST['directorder'] ;
$other = $_REQUEST['other'] ;
$Productdescription = $_REQUEST['Productdescription'] ;
$OctDates = $_REQUEST['OctDates'] ;
$NovDates = $_REQUEST['NovDates'] ;
$DecDates = $_REQUEST['DecDates'] ;
$Power = $_REQUEST['Power'] ;
$Powerfor = $_REQUEST['Powerfor'] ;
$websitepermission = $_REQUEST['websitepermission'] ;
$checkbox = $_REQUEST['checkbox'] ;
$Rules = $_REQUEST['Rules'] ;
$msg = 
"Business Name: " . $busname . "\r\n" . 
"Applicant Name: " . $Applicant . "\r\n" . 
"Street: " . $street . "\r\n" . 
"apartment: " . $apartment . "\r\n" . 
"City: " . $city . "\r\n" . 
"Province: " . $province . "\r\n" . 
"Postal Code: " . $postal . "\r\n" . 
"Main Phone: " . $mainphone . "\r\n" . 
"Cell Phone: " . $cellphone . "\r\n" . 
"Email: " . $email_address . "\r\n" .
"Website: " . $website . "\r\n" . 
"Product Category: " . $category . "\r\n" . 
"Direct Order: " . $directorder . "\r\n" . 
"Other: " . $other . "\r\n" . 
"Product Description: " . $Productdescription . "\r\n" . 
"October Dates: " . $OctDates . "\r\n" . 
"November Dates: " . $NovDates . "\r\n" . 
"December Dates: " . $DecDates . "\r\n" . 
"Power: " . $Power . "\r\n" . 
"Power For: " . $Powerfor . "\r\n" . 
"Website Permission: " . $websitepermission . "\r\n" . 
"Info to give out: " . $checkbox . "\r\n" . 
"Read the Rules: " . $Rules  ;


/*
The following function checks for email injection.
Specifically, it checks for carriage returns - typically used by spammers to inject a CC list.
*/

function isInjected($str) {
    $injections = array('(\n+)',
    '(\r+)',
    '(\t+)',
    '(%0A+)',
    '(%0D+)',
    '(%08+)',
    '(%09+)'
    );
    $inject = join('|', $injections);
    $inject = "/$inject/i";
    if(preg_match($inject,$str)) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}
/*
// If the user tries to access this script directly, redirect them to the feedback form,
if (!isset($_REQUEST['email_address'])) {
header( "Location: $feedback_page" );
}

// If the form fields are empty, redirect to the error page.
if (empty($Applicant) || empty($email_address)) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}
*/
/* 
If email injection is detected, redirect to the error page.
If you add a form field, you should add it here.
*//*
elseif ( isInjected($email_address) || isInjected($Applicant)  || isInjected($busname) || isInjected($postal)  || isInjected($Street)  || isInjected($city)  || isInjected($Applicant)  ||) {
header( "Location: $error_page" );
}

// If we passed all previous tests, send the email then redirect to the thank you page.
else*/ {

    mail( "$webmaster_email", "Feedback Form Results", $msg );

    header( "Location: $thankyou_page" );
}
?>
```

And the result I get emailed to me is:

> Business Name:
>
> Applicant Name: applicant name
>
> Street: www.tallgrassapparel.com
>
> apartment:
>
> City:
>
> Province:
>
> Postal Code:
>
> Main Phone:
>
> Cell Phone:
>
> Email:
>
> Website:
>
> Product Category:
>
> Direct Order: direct
>
> Other: other
>
> Product Description: product description October Dates: 1 November Dates: 19 December Dates: 24
>
> Power: Yes
>
> Power For: Taking over world
>
> Website Permission: No
>
> Info to give out:
>
> Read the Rules: Signature

Comment: Your HTML is badly formed

Answer (score 3):

Your form fields don't match up what you're grabbing from `$_POST`

From the form:

```html
    <td colspan="4"><div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="prependedtext"></label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <span class="input-group-addon">Business Name:</span>
          <input id="prependedtext" name="prependedtext" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text" required="">
        </div>  
      </div>
```

Your business name field is called `prependedtext` but you're expecting `busname`

The ones that work are named consistently. Go through the form and verify the names of all the input fields and make sure they all match.

Furthermore, it looks like someone just copied and pasted the code without double checking it.

```html
<input id="street" name="street" class="form-control" placeholder="" type="text" required="">
```

Is used for a bunch of fields.